# Copy file from UNIX to Windows using script

Tags: python, windows, shell, unix

I would like to write a script to automate a task which I do manually everyday. This task requires me to download some files from a UNIX server (Solaris) to my desktop (Windows XP) using WinSCP. Is there any way to copy/move the files from a path in the UNIX server to a path in my Windows XP PC using Python or shell script?

Comment: Please check my post : http://sundarpari.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-download-from-unix-server-using.html and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to use python, then you can use paramiko library. It has sftp support. Once you have the file on windows, use shutils library to move it to your path on windows

Comment: yeah paramiko is nice! I recommend you also

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. May I know is there anything need to be configured in the client PC (like installing Cygwin)?

Comment: I guess you will need to install python. Then install `setuptools` for python and then do an `easy_install parammiko`. Let me know if you need more help. Look here as well http://vijaymurthy.blogspot.in/2011/03/installing-paramiko-for-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Cygwin together with rsync? You could write a small bash script that uses rsync to fetch the files you need, and run this as a daily cron job.